# Issue AWS mobile hub sign-in - NotAuthorizedException for identity pool

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, federated-identity, aws-mobilehub

I am referring to AWS Mobile Hub Developer Guide (for integrating email-based user sign-in) http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/amhd-dg.pdf

Topic titled : Setup your app for AWS Mobile services (Android - Java)

Last step no 8 outcome should be "IdentityManager: Got user ID: us-east-1:abcabcabc-0be6-444e-b101-abcabcabc"
but I am getting "D/IdentityManager: Got user ID: null"

Stack trace for exception:

```
E/IdentityManager: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: d275fc19-b700-11e7-bac5-5d9ca7c93439)
                                                                                   com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException: Unauthenticated access is not supported for this identity pool. (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotAuthorizedException; Request ID: d275fc19-b700-11e7-bac5-5d9ca7c93439)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:729)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.invoke(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:559)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.getId(AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java:445)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.getIdentityId(AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider.java:172)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCredentialsProvider.java:402)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.auth.CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.getIdentityId(CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider.java:465)
                                                                                       at com.amazonaws.mobile.auth.core.IdentityManager$1.run(IdentityManager.java:334)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


------------------------

D/IdentityManager: Got user ID: null
```

Comment: Hi,

You would get that error if you tried running your app without also following the steps in the "Add Mobile Hub User Sign-in to Your Mobile App" section of the developer guide.  I assume you set it up as required.  If you do that then you must have the user log in.

Kevin

Comment: @KevinR, In the process of migrating from aws-sdk-android 2.4.2 to 2.6.0 it is required to enable 'Enable access to unauthenticated identities' in 'Unauthenticated identities' for an 'Identity Pool' (as per the solution provided by AWS support center).

Comment: I'm not sure what you are referring to when you say it is require to enable access to unauthenticated identities, that should not be the case.  A few questions: Are you using Mobile Hub for this?  Do you have Mandatory sign in (or optional) for the user sign in feature?  Also have you looked at the migration guide? (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile-hub/latest/developerguide/aws-mobile-sdk-migrate.html).

Comment: Yes, I'm using Mobile Hub, and I have the Mandatory sign in for the user sign. Also I have refer to the same migration guide. (point 2.c is for the sign-in UI)